# React Components state vs props Dynamic Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been experimenting couple of days with ReactJS and ES6 and created couple of components i.e. `<InputText />`, `<InputNumber />`, `<InputEmail />`, that are being used in the component `<ContactsEdit />`.

It seems really strange that even though I have read many tutorials my child components refuse to `render()` the `{this.state.Firstname}` even though I tried `componentWillMount`, `componentDidMount`, `this.setState`, `this.state` with `this.forceUpdate()`, but they will render fine the `this.props.Firstname`

I would welcome any kind of suggestions or help. The source can be found at [github](https://github.com/karanaso/react-es6-input-components)

Thanks :)

`
export default class ContactsEdit extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.contactId = this.props.params.id;
    this.persistence = new Persistence('mock');

    this.state = {
        contact : {}
    };

}

componentDidMount() {
    this.persistence.getContactById( this.contactId ).then( (resolve) => {
        this.setState({ contact : resolve.data });
        this.data = resolve.data;
    }).catch( (reject) => {
        console.log(reject);
    }) ;

    this.forceUpdate();
}

onChange(id,newValue)  {
    this.state.contact[ id ] = newValue;
    this.forceUpdate();
}

saveRecord( object ) {
    console.log( this.state );
}

render() {
    return (            
        <div className="ContactsEdit">
            <h2>Contact Edit (Parent) id : {this.props.params.id}, FullName : {this.state.contact.Firstname} {this.state.contact.Lastname}</h2>
            <div className="row">                    
                <InputText id="Firstname" fieldName={this.state.contact.Firstname}  labelName="Firstname" onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} divClass="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" />
                <InputText id="Lastname"  fieldName={this.state.contact.Lastname}  labelName="Lastname"  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} divClass="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" />
                <InputText id="SocSecId"  fieldName={this.state.contact.SocSecId}  labelName="SocSecId"  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} divClass="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" />
                <InputText id="DriverLicId"  fieldName={this.state.contact.DriverLicId}  labelName="DriverLicId"  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} divClass="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" />
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

}

`

`
export default class InputText extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);         
    this.state = { fieldName : this.props.fieldname}; 
}

componentWillMount() {
    //this.state.fieldName = this.props.fieldname;
    //this.forceUpdate();
}

updateState(evt) {
    //this.setState( {fieldName : evt.target.value} );
    this.props.onChange( evt.target.id, evt.target.value     );
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className={this.props.divClass}>
            <hr />
            <label> {this.props.labelName} </label>
            <div>{this.props.fieldName}</div> 
            <div>{this.state.fieldName}</div> 
            <input 
                type="text" 
                id={this.props.id} 
                value={this.props.fieldName} 
                onChange={this.updateState.bind(this)} 
                className="form-control"
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

}
`

Comment: Welcome to Stack! Just post the relevant code here in your question, which will (hopefully) remove the downvotes and get you the answers you need.

Comment: Thanks :) I will do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props` doesn't exist in the constructor function until after its run, binding `this` to an instance of the class. Use the `props` that are passed in from the parent (in the argument)

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { fieldName: props.fieldname }
}
```

`componentWillMount` is replaced by using ES6 class constructor

Also you should not modify `this.state` directly. It won't cause react to call `render()`. Only set the initial state in constructor. Everywhere else, call `this.setState({ data: newData })`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I am posting the topic and the GitHub link is that I have tried everything. I know that using `this.state` is not best practice and I have used it in conjuction with `this.forceUpdate` because the `this.setState()` would not work.

I am also aware that `componentWillUpdate()` has been replaced in ES6 but removing it and only using the `constructor()` wouldn’t do the job for me.

I have also tried

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState({ fieldName : 'something' })
// …
```

but that only led to hardcoding the value into my component. I have tried returning the value using a promise:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    MyPromise( (resolve) => {
       this.setState({ fieldName : resolve})
    }
// …
```

but that did not work either.

So I started wondering if maybe there is something wrong with my gulpfile (thus providing the GitHub repo so someone with more expertise could maybe check and help).

Very strangely, though, the `this.props` solution worked even though I understand it’s not the best practice.